# System of linear Fredholm integral equations

Tags: reference-request, integral-equations

I am looking for a reference for theorems and results talking about the existence and the uniqueness of the system of linear Fredholm integral equations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case, have you tried googling "system of linear Fredholm integral equations"? I found quite a few papers dealing with numerical methods, but I'm pretty sure one of them has a citation for some original work on existence

Comment: I also found many of these articles. But did not find a path to the basic theory.

Comment: This paper deals with constant sign solutions, but it may be helpful https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:ACAP.0000013257.42126.ca